# How to use the `using` keyword in gcc 10.4?

Tags: c++, gcc, enums, c++20, scoped-enums

I am compiling with the C-Stadard 20 using this argument: "-std=gnu++2a". Thus I thought I am able to use the `using` keyword as following:

```
void anyfunc(const foo::bar& value) {
    switch (foo:bar(value)) {
        using enum foo:bar;
        case George:
            // ...
        case Mary:
            // ...
        default:
            // ...
    }
}
```

But my new gcc won't compile it because it does not know the 'using' keyword:

```
main.cpp:69:11: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘enum’
   69 |     using enum foo::var;
      |           ^~~~
```

The gcc version I use is:

```
arm-linux-g++.br_real (Buildroot 2022.02.5) 10.4.0
```

See here my full minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace foo {
    enum class bar {
        George = 0,
        Mary,
        Martin,
        // ...
    };
}

void anyfunc(const foo::bar value) {
    // This is working
    switch (foo::bar(value)) {
        case foo::bar::George:
            printf("George");
        case foo::bar::Mary:
            printf("Mary");
        default:
            printf("Default");      
    }

    // This does not compile
    // switch (foo::bar(value)) {
    //     using enum foo::bar;
    //     case George:
    //         printf("George");
    //     case Mary:
    //         printf("Mary");
    //     default:
    //         printf("Default");       
    // }
}

int main() {
    anyfunc(foo::bar::Mary);
    // ..
}
```

Comment: `foo:bar` seems to be missing a `:` too

Comment: Okay, I See my provided code snipped is not enough. I'll prepare a full minimal example.

Comment: GCC 10 doesn't have `using enum`, I think?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Nope! It was added in g++11. I added a note about that to the answer

Comment: Okay, sorry for my missing colon and the missing minimal example. I added it now above. And thank you @TedLyngmo to provide the solution faster than I me adding the minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need `::` to separate the namespace from the `enum class`
- You do *not* need to cast `value` into a `foo::bar`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    enum class bar {
        George, Mary
    };
}

void anyfunc(const foo::bar value) {  // prefer to take it by value instead
    switch (value) {                  // no cast
        using enum foo::bar;          // note ::
        case George:
            std::cout << "George\n";
            break;
        case Mary:
            std::cout << "Mary\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "default\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    anyfunc(foo::bar::Mary);
}
```

Output:

```
Mary
```

Note: [`using enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Using-enum-declaration) ([P1099R5](https://wg21.link/P1099R5)) was added in g++ 11 so you will probably not be able to use it with your `arm-linux-g++.br_real (Buildroot 2022.02.5) 10.4.0` compiler.

Comment: I've found `using enum` has the same problems as `using namespace`.

Comment: @Spencer Sure, but not if done correctly, like above, I assume? It's all a matter of keeping the `using` scope as small as possible.

Comment: No, sometimes you don't want to be hoisting all of the names. I'd like a `notusing` keyword but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @Spencer You can already do that by scoping it: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/x9c5ebxfE)

Comment: If `Max` were in that list (as is the case for nearly all of my enums), there might still be a problem.

Comment: @Spencer I don't see how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250869/discussion-between-spencer-and-ted-lyngmo).